# Chaining Network Requests RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I am relatively new to RxSwift, and functional programming for that matter. I have an app where I need to make a sequential set of network calls, each call depends upon output of the other. How I have architected the app, these calls are not made anywhere close to the view or view controllers - they are handled by data provider classes which perform business logic on the response data. As I understand good Rx design, subscribers should stay at the top of chain, not in classes like these that purely perform business and functional logic on the data.

I am creating a contrived and simplified example for illustration from these requests that return Singles:

```
func loginRequest(_ data: LoginData) -> Single<LoginResponse> {
    return Single.create { observer -> Disposable in
        let request = LoginRequestWith(data)
        networkClient.send(request) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                observer(.success(response))
            case .failure(let error):
                observer(.error(error))
            }
        }
        return Disposables.create {
            networkClient.cancelRequest()
        }
    }
}

func userRequest(_ data: UserData) -> Single<UserResponse> {
    return Single.create { observer -> Disposable in
        let request = InfoRequestWith(data)
        networkClient.send(request) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                observer(.success(response))
            case .failure(let error):
                observer(.error(error))
            }
        }
        return Disposables.create {
            networkClient.cancelRequest()
        }
    }
}

func infoRequest(_ data: InfoData) -> Single<InfoResponse> {
    return Single.create { observer -> Disposable in
        let request = InfoRequestWith(data)
        networkClient.send(request) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                observer(.success(response))
            case .failure(let error):
                observer(.error(error))
            }
        }
        return Disposables.create {
            networkClient.cancelRequest()
        }
    }
}
```

These requests are working as intended, however I am calling and handling them improperly using subscriptions / dispose bags in the provider classes to get them to work. What I want to do is chain them together using a FlatMap or more appropriate chain of operators. And this is where I get stuck.

```
func login() -> Observable<InfoData> {
  webServices.loginRequest(loginData)
    // verify success?
    .flatMap { result in
      // Now call userRequest passing the response from the first
      // and from that infoRequest passing the response from the second
      // Which should return the Observable<InfoData> 
    }
}
```

Where I am messing up? I get errors around the FlatMap but I understand that these are best to use with Singles. My errors seem to revolve around not mapping the response correctly to a new observable:

```
webServices.loginRequest(loginData)
.flatMap { response -> PrimitiveSequence<SingleTrait, Result> in
   return response
}
```

> Xcode Error: Reference to generic type 'Result' requires arguments in
>   <...>

And then how do I chain call into the subsequent request after a previous one. Thank you very much for any assistance.

Comment: Please share the errors you are getting for `flatMap`.

Comment: added error message to question

Comment: So each method in `webServices` return a different model wrapped in a Single sequence. Every time you use a method you can do operations on and then, eventually, you'll use the final result as a result of an observation. 
You can use `flatMap` to chain those request and use the previous value, as you've already done. Like this
```webServices.loginRequest(loginData). flatMap { response -> Single<UserResponse> in
return webServices.userRequest( the UserData model )
}
```
and so on -

Comment: Thank you @Dimitris - this info was extremely helpful - I also realized that because I wasn't subscribing to the data streams nothing was actually happening as I would expect - I will chalk it up as a hard lessoned learned for a Rx beginner